# Custom Gradle task hangs

Tags: android, gradle

I am putting together a Gradle task that will start an Android device using Genymotion. The task does launch the emulator but hangs at this stage:

```
Building 0% > :startEmulator
```

How do I tell it to continue once the emulator has launched? My task looks like:

```
task startEmulator(type: Exec) {
  executable 'sh'
  args "-c", "/Applications/Genymotion.app/Contents/MacOS/player.app/Contents/MacOS/player --vm-name 'Google Nexus 6P - 7.0.0 - API 24 - 1440x2560'"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The task hangs since it probably works in foreground and does not exit. Gradle waits for this task to finish, so it waits forever. What might help here is to run the task in background. You may find [this](https://github.com/marc0der/gradle-spawn-plugin) plugin useful.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so with this can i start my emulator, move onto the next task (run tests) and then kill the process at the end ?